# Element is not changing its appearance on click - Selenium C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I have next problem: in the application, when I do mouse over or click on rating stars, rating stars become yellow. It is working on the application correctly. But, when I wrote and ran Selenium test, these stars are not changing their appearance on click or hover (moveToElement).
I tried it with this code:

```
IWebElement star = Utility.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[@title='Good']"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Utility.Driver;
js.ExecuteScript("var elem=arguments[0]; setTimeout(function() {elem.click();}, 100)", star);
```

and this one:

```
Actions action = new Actions(Utility.Driver);        action.MoveToElement(Utility.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[@title='Good']"))).Click().Perform();
```

but nothing happens.
Selenium test is passing because star elements are visible, but I do not know why they are not changing their appearance on click or mouse over.

Comment: What is the actual JavaScript event that occurs for them to change? Also, is the behaviour different in other browsers?

Comment: What is the URL to the page or maybe post the actual code of the site here so we can better help you.

Comment: It is really difficult to comment without looking at the actual page